# Ubuntu 18.04.2 hangs (stop job running) during shutdown on Dell Inspiron 14 7000

Tags: shutdown, freeze

I know this is a common problem but I have tried other solutions suggested.
When I shutdown/reboot my laptop, Ubuntu hangs.

The screen message says "Stop Job running".
[Screen Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mfzpJ.jpg)

My laptop is a `Dell Inspiron 14 7000` with a `128GB SSD + 1TB HHD`. Windows is installed on the SSD and Ubuntu on the HHD.

I have tried the solutions such as turning off `Automatic Suspend` and set `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="acpi=force"`

Answer (score 0):

Try loading a different (earlier) kernel, from advanced options during Boot. See if the problem persists.

https://blog.seibert-media.com/2018/01/04/log-book-linux-cpu-lockups/